# Ubuntu 16.04 - Trying to write an image to my microSD card but getting "no such file or directory"

Tags: 16.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

I am following this tutorial (https://fossbytes.com/install-ubuntu-mate-on-raspberry-pi-2-3/) in order to install Ubuntu MATE on my Raspberry Pi 3. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 in order to download the Ubuntu MATE image, and I'm currently trying to write the image to my microSD card which will eventually be placed in my Pi.

I downloaded the Ubuntu MATE image from the official website. Afterwards, I have done the following steps in my terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue xz-utils
unxz ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz
```

After the step above, I get the error:

```
unxz: ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz: 
No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assuming you saved the compressed archive in the `~/Downloads` folder...

The program `unxz`can't find the file because it is looking for the file in the current folder. When you open a terminal the current folder of the terminal is `/home/$USER`, where `$USER` is your user name.

When you download a file using something like Firefox, it puts the file in `/home/$USER/Downloads`. You can either change the current folder to the location with the command:

```
cd Downloads
```

and the use the previous command:

```
unxz ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz
```

Or you can tell `unxz` the full path of the file:

```
unxz /home/$USER/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz
```

**Note:** Ubuntu is case sensitive. `Downloads`, `downloads`, and `DOWNLOADS` are 3 different folders.

Hope this helps